# Spectrum of the Orr Sommerfeld equation

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, spectral-theory

The Orr Sommerfeld equation is as follows $$\psi''-k^2 \psi - \frac{U''}{U-c}\psi=0$$ where $\psi(y)$ is a complex valued function on $[0,2\pi]$ satisfying Dirichlet boundary conditions $\psi(0)=\psi(2\pi)=0$. $U(y)$ is a known, real valued function. $c$ is a complex number, $k$ is real.

This arises in fluid dynamics by linearizing the Euler equation of ideal fluid dynamics about a steady state $U(y)$ (the so called shear flow in a two dimensional channel) and considering a perturbation stream function of the form

$\hat{\psi}(x,y,t)=\psi(y) e^{ik(x-ct)}$

I have a few questions regarding this equation

i) It is claimed that this is an eigenvalue problem with $c$ as the complex eigenvalue. Why is this so? How does one rewrite this equation as an eigenvalue problem in $c$?

ii) Since the coefficients of the operator are real, eigenvalues occur in complex conjugate pairs. ( My suspicion is that they are talking about the operator $L\psi= \psi'' - k^2 \psi$)

iii) There exists a continuous spectrum for all (real) $c$ between  $U_{min} \leq c \leq U_{max}$ with eigenfunctions that have a discontinuous derivative at $y_c$ where $y_c$ is the point such that $U(y_c)=c$

Comment: (i)  To see that it is an eigenvalue problem, multiply through by $U-c$, and rearrange.  You will get something like $L\psi = c M\psi$, where $L$ and $M$ are linear operators that depend upon $U(y)$.  Since the only explicit $x$ dependence is via the second derivative, (assuming this is what $\psi''$ means), the eigenfunctions as functions of $x$ will be complex exponentials.
(ii)  No, they are talking about the equation $L\psi = c M\psi$ (whatever $L$ and $M$ are).(iii)  That one I would have to think about.